# PDE: Separation of variables on a non-"nice" domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, tensor-products, orthogonality, geometric-topology

So, a typical strategy for solving certain PDE's is separation of variables. I understand this only works on domains that can be represented by a cartesian product like: $[0,L] X [0,H]$. Therefore, we are pretty much limited to rectangular and circular domains for separation of variables to work.

I want to see a better explanation of WHY separation of variables fails on - lets say - a triangular domain, other than: "well, you can't express a triangular region as a cartesian product like $[0,L] X [0,H]$."

I'd also like to have an answer that ties in the idea of orthogonality - I think these are all related but currently unable to put all the pieces together in a nice way that I can understand.

Also, is there anyway we can make use of a transformation to the triangular region to turn it into a region that allows the variables to separate?

Please help me put all these ideas together! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that you _can_ use separation of variables on triangles, you just need a "nice" coordinate change to do it as shown [here](https://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol3/S01061.pdf).

Comment: If your PDE is the Laplace equation or something related, you'll want to look at [conformal mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).

Comment: @Mike James Johnson : There is a fundamental forgetting in your assumption : The solution of the PDE is not only one term made of a product of functions of each variable. The solution is a finite or infinite sum of such terms, each one found with the "separation of variables". Each term has an arbitrary factor. So, for any shape of domain, the factors have to be computed so that the whole function fits the boundary conditions. Generally the fitting is very arduous. In case of rectangular domain, the fitting is more easy. That is why the rectangular domain is often chosen for school problems.